# AngularJS: Ideal way to handle HTML Templates?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a project right now where we have several different `Tasks`, each `Task` has it's own way of displaying data, they are minor data changes that don't need individual controllers, and views.

For example, one task might have a heading that shows the `Username`, the next task doesn't need a username and replaces it with a `Behavior`.

Here is what I am doing right now:

```
<div id="event-list">
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="isHidden=!isHidden;" ng-repeat="event in events" ng-init="isHidden=false;">

            <!-- Template 1 -->
            <div ng-if="taskCategory == 'taskExampleOne'">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h1>{{event.EventName}}</h1>
                    <p class="description">Username: {{ event.User.Name }}</p>
                    <p class="date">{{ event.RecordDateUtc | moment: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }}</p>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="isHidden" class="body event-show-hide-animation">
                    <img src="{{ event.SnapshotJpg }}" />
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Record Date: </dt>
                        <dd>{{ event.RecordDateUtc | moment: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM A' }} {{ event.RecordDateTz }}</dd>
                    </dl>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="viewEventDetails( event )">View Event</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Template 1 -->

            <!-- Template 2 -->
            <div ng-if="taskCategory == 'taskExampleTwo'">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h1>{{event.EventName}}</h1>
                    <p class="description">
                        <span>Username: {{ event.User.Name }}</span>
                        <span>Behavior: {{ event.BehaviorNames }}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="date">{{ event.RecordDateUtc | moment: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }}</p>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="isHidden" class="body event-show-hide-animation">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Event: </dt>
                        <dd>{{ event.EventId }}</dd>

                        <dt>Group: </dt>
                        <dd>{{ event.QueryKey.GroupIds[0] }}</dd>

                        <dt>Record Date: </dt>
                        <dd>{{ event.RecordDateUtc | moment: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM A' }} {{ event.RecordDateTz }}</dd>
                    </dl>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="viewEventDetails( event )">View Event</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Template 2 -->

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So there is quite a bit of waste by repeating the elements, however I feel as though it is a bit more readable splitting the entire template rather than having a ton of `ng-if` conditions for each piece of information.

Is there a better way to handle these templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create an angularjs directive. See this [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r45beMseazoRNvMCCuRk)

You can either Create one template for both todo items and use ng-show / hide to select which elements to present or create two different directives for each case.

```
myApp.directive("todo", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: "task.tpl.html"
  };
});
```

Notice the file template `todo.tpl.html`

```
 <div class="heading">
      <h1>{{event.EventName}}</h1>
      <p class="description">Username: {{ event.User.Name }}</p>
      <span ng-show="event.BehaviorNames">Behavior: {{ event.BehaviorNames }}</span>
      <p class="date">{{ event.RecordDateUtc | moment: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!isHidden" class="body event-show-hide-animation">
      <img src="{{ event.SnapshotJpg }}" />
      <dl>
        <dt ng-show="event.BehaviorNames">Event: </dt>
        <dd ng-show="event.BehaviorNames">{{ event.EventId }}</dd>
        <dt ng-show="event.BehaviorNames">Group: </dt>
        <dd ng-show="event.BehaviorNames">{{ event.QueryKey.GroupIds[0] }}</dd>
        <dt>Record Date: </dt>
        <dd>{{ event.RecordDateUtc | moment: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM A' }} {{ event.RecordDateTz }}</dd>
      </dl>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="viewEventDetails( event )">View Event</button>
    </div>
```

You can read more about custom directives [enter link description here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)